# How to Bind Fileupload to Image control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web form, in web form i have two contorol: asp:fileupload control that accept .png file type and asp:Image. 
i want to bind fileupload selected file to image control and can't this, any body can help me?
thanks.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Image-after-selected-selecting-file-name-in-HTML-Input-FileUpload.aspx

Comment: i check first link, it is ok.tanks